# Check cells emptiness of a certain column, if all of them are, hide whole column

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, html-table

I'm trying to check if `<td>`s with class 'checkthisone' are empty, and if they are hide whole column. I am trying to do this via jquery. The table is created in loop from a wordpress page so I could not find a way to do that with php.

The table HTML is like this:

```
     <table>
          <tr>
            <th>header</th>
            <th id="checking-tds-header">header</th>
            <th>header</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td class="checkthisone"></td>
            <td>info</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td class="checkthisone"></td>
            <td>info</td>
          </tr>
    </table>
```

The PHP code that displays the table is here: https://paste.ee/p/yrQpg

I want to check cells with class 'temizleme' in this code. The relevant section is:

```
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    ?>      
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="mangaep-episode" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'kacinci_bolum', true );  ?>
            <?php $bolum_aciklamasi = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'bolum_aciklamasi', true);
                if ( ! empty ( $bolum_aciklamasi ) ) {  ?>          
                <span><?php echo $bolum_aciklamasi;  ?></span>
                <?php } ?>
            </a>    
        </td>
        <td><?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { the_views(); } ?></td>
        <td class="down"><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'cevirmen', true );  ?></td>
        <td class="down"><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'editor', true );  ?></td>
        <td class="down temizleme"><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'temizleme', true );  ?></td> 
        <td class="down">
                <?php $indirme_linki = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'indirme_linki', true);
                if ( ! empty ( $indirme_linki ) ) { ?>          
                <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $indirme_linki;  ?>" class="mangaep-down">İNDİR</a>
                <?php } ?>                  
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: This should be perfectly achievable in PHP, and would be preferable to adding the functionality client-side. If you include the code that creates the table in PHP, we can take a look.

Comment: @FluffyKitten i shared a link for it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Exclude the `<tr>` in your PHP**

To exclude an entire row:

1. get the post_meta value(s) at the start of the while loop
2. Check if it is empty or not
3. If it isn't empty, display the row.

For example, to check the value in the `temizleme` in the post_meta:

```
<?php
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

   /* 1. Get the post_meta value of temizleme */
   $temizleme = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'temizleme', true );

    /* 2. check if temizleme has a value */
    if (!empty($temizleme)) {

        /* 3. if temizleme isn't empty, display the row */
        ?>      
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a class="mangaep-episode" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'kacinci_bolum', true );  ?>
                <?php $bolum_aciklamasi = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'bolum_aciklamasi', true);
                    if ( ! empty ( $bolum_aciklamasi ) ) {  ?>          
                    <span><?php echo $bolum_aciklamasi;  ?></span>
                    <?php } ?>
                </a>    
            </td>
            <td><?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { the_views(); } ?></td>
            <td class="down"><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'cevirmen', true );  ?></td>
            <td class="down"><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'editor', true );  ?></td>
            <td class="down temizleme"><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'temizleme', true );  ?></td> 
            <td class="down">
                <?php $indirme_linki = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'indirme_linki', true);
                if ( ! empty ( $indirme_linki ) ) { ?>          
                    <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $indirme_linki;  ?>" class="mangaep-down">İNDİR</a>
                <?php } ?>                  
            </td>
        </tr>

    <?php  } /* 3. end if (!empty(temizleme)) */  ?>    

<?php  endwhile; ?>
```

**Check more than one value**

The code you linked to is different to the code you included in your question so I'm not sure exactly what you need to check.

So if you want to check more than one value, just get all of the values at the start of the while loop and check if they have values.

If they ALL must have a value use `&&` in your `if` statement, if ANY can have a value use `||`. e.g.

```
<?php
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

   /* 1. Get the post_meta values to check */
   $temizleme = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'temizleme', true );
   $kacinci_bolum= get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'kacinci_bolum', true );

    /* 2. check that BOTH have a value */
    if (!empty($temizleme) && !empty($kacinci_bolum)) {
    ?>      
        <tr>
            [... display your tds the same way as above...]
        </tr>

    <?php  } /* end if (!empty...) */  ?>   
<?php  endwhile;   ?>
```

**To Hide a Column in your PHP**

To check the values of a column, you will need to:

1. Loop through the posts, saving the values into an array
2. Check all the values of "temizleme" in the array, and if any of them have a value, set a flag to use when displaying the table (e.g. we set `$bTemizlemeColumnIsEmpty` to false in the example below)
3. Loop through the data array to display the information in the table. If our flag indicates the column is empty (i.e. `$bTemizlemeColumnIsEmpty` is true), then don't display the `<td>` for "temizleme"

For example:

```
<?php

$postdata = array(); /* array to save data for ALL posts */

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

   /* 1. Save all the post data in an array */
   $row = array(); /* array to save data for THIS post */

   $row["temizleme"] = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'temizleme', true );
   $row["kacinci_bolum"] = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'kacinci_bolum', true );
   $row["bolum_aciklamasi"] = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'bolum_aciklamasi', true );

   [etc...]

   $postdata[]  = $row; /* add this data to the $postdata array */
<?php  endwhile;   ?>   


/* 2. check the values of temizleme */

$bTemizlemeColumnIsEmpty = true;
foreach ($postdata as $row)
    if (!empty($row["temizleme"]))  $bTemizlemeColumnIsEmpty = false;

/* if any of the cells have a value, $bTemizlemeColumnIsEmpty will be false after we finish this loop */


/* 3. now loop through all the row to display the table */
foreach ($postdata as $row){
?>
     <tr>
        <td>
                <a class="mangaep-episode" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $row["kacinci_bolum"];  ?>
                <?php if ( ! empty ( $row["bolum_aciklamasi"] ) ) { ?>          
                    <span><?php echo $row["bolum_aciklamasi"];  ?></span>
                    <?php } ?>
                </a>    
            </td>
            <td><?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { the_views(); } ?></td>
            <td class="down"><?php echo $row["cevirmen"];  ?></td>
            <td class="down"><?php echo $row["editor"];  ?></td>

            <?php 
            /* 4. only display this td if  $bTemizlemeColumnIsEmpty is false */
            if ( !$bTemizlemeColumnIsEmpty ){
            ?>
                <td class="down temizleme"><?php echo $row["temizleme"];  ?></td> 
            <?php  }   ?>   


            <td class="down">
                <?php if ( ! empty ( $row["indirme_linki"] ) ) {    ?>          
                    <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $row["indirme_linki"];  ?>" class="mangaep-down">İNDİR</a>
                <?php } ?>                  
            </td>
    </tr>

<?php  } /* end foreach */  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".checkthisone").each(function(){   // check each class
      if($(this).text() == ""){         // if the <td> has nothing in it, enter this condition
         $(this).parent("tr").hide();   // hide the entire <tr>
      }
   });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".checkthisone").each(function(){
      if($(this).text() == ""){
         $(this).parent("tr").hide();
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
          <tr>
            <th>header</th>
            <th id="checking-tds-header">header</th>
            <th>header</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td class="checkthisone"></td>
            <td>info</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td class="checkthisone">stuff</td>
            <td>info</td>
          </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to make use of `:empty` selector

```js
$( "#checking-tds-header" ).hide();
$( "td.checkthisone:empty" ).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
          <tr>
            <th>header</th>
            <th id="checking-tds-header">header</th>
            <th>header</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td class="checkthisone"></td>
            <td>info</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td class="checkthisone"></td>
            <td>info</td>
          </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: i think that code "$( "#checking-tds-header" ).hide()" hides header directly. I want to check if all cells in that column are empty. I need to hide the header with cells after checking